# Ayuda con migraciones en Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

Cuando realizo la migración clásica para iniciar mi BD en PHPMyadmin me sale estos errores, pero a todo ello si me genera las 2 tablas por defecto pero otras tablas ya no me las acepta... Alguien me puede ayudar por favor es urgente

> c:\xampp\htdocs\prueba1>php artisan migrate
>
> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int
>   unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not
>   null, `email` varchar(255) not null,   `password` varchar(255) not
>   null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` tim   estamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> In Connection.php line 458:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'users' already exists

Answer (score 3):

Te está Indicando el error que la tabla users ya existe, si no tienes problema en eliminarla ejecuta entonces el siguiente comando

Cómo estás usando la versión 5.5 ya tienes disponible el siguiente comando para llevar a cabo la migración

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Para que con dicho comando se borren las tablas de tu base de datos y se hagan todas desde cero

Para el problema final que mencionas en los comentarios te comento se resuelve así:

1. abre el archivo que se llama `AppServiceProvider.php` (dicho archivo esta dentro de la carpeta `app/providers`) y dentro del método `boot()` agrega esta línea

`Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`

2. Y en la parte superior justo despues del llamado al namespace `App`, agrega también esta línea

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

3. Repite el comando:

`php artisan migrate:fresh`

> (este comando se encuentra disponible desde la versión 5.5 de Laravel
>   Framework)

---

> También te doy como al ternativa para este error que se presenta,
>   actualizar a la versión de mysql 5.7, considerando que solo si es
>   factible y siempre con respaldos PLENAMENTE FUNCIONALES DE TUS BASES
>   DE DATOS

Comment: Oye Alfredo gracias... pero ahora me sale esto si lo habia utilizado pero igual siguen mas errores

Comment: c:\xampp\htdocs\prueba1>php artisan migrate:fresh
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.

In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQ
  L: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: te añado el modo de resolverlo a mi respuesta

Comment: @WilliamsCamonesMoreno te añadí la solución

Comment: sería bueno agregar a la solución de las keys que el número 191 de defaultStringLenght es porque al usar utf8mb4 cada letra ocupa 4 bytes y 191 x 4 = 764 te mantiene debajo del límite (767)

Answer (score 0):

Al fin lo resolví, el detalle es que obligatoriamente creo se debe usar homestead para laravel o tan simple como cambiar de servidor o paquete de servicio para php y mysql, como puede ser el uso de LARAGON, útil herramienta que contiene un servidor virtual incorporado, php, mysql, además tiene un terminal buenaso (cmder), y un servidor de BD (HeidiSQL)  ya salí de mi problema ahora a continuar.. Gracias por la ayuda a los que respondieron... WJCM

Comment: no tiene que ser obligatorio homestead para laravel es no es así

Comment: je, heidiSQL es un cliente

Comment: No, Homestead no es obligatorio para el uso de laravel, pero en la documentación si lo recomienda para usuarios más avanzados, tal vez fui muy estricto en mi comentario, y al respecto de HeidiSQL, lo que pude investigar es que nació con Mysql-Front (también lo use hace mucho tiempo) es un SGBD muy bueno ahora mucho mejor inclusive...